# Elimination of tickets

Tags: probability

There are 8 tickets numbered from 1 to 8. They are randomly paired, and larger numbered ticket of each pair is eliminated, leaving only four tickets (the smaller ones in each pair). This process is repeated again, leaving only two tickets.
What is the probability that one of the remaining tickets is numbered 4?

I figured out that one of the remaining tickets must be 1, and analyzed all possible favorable cases to get the answer. It did work out, but after a lot of confusion.

Is there a more elegant method to solve this and perhaps generalize the result for n tickets?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 phases:

- PHASE1: 4 pairs are formed and highest one eliminated.
- PHASE2: 2 pairs are formed and highest one eliminated.

Now since 4 has to be at the end, in each of the phases it is paired with a higher number.

In PHASE1, there are 4 options for pairing 4 (with 5,6,7,8). Also you have to ensure that one of these 4 numbers goes to PHASE2, so that we can pair 4 with it then. Hence you have to ensure that a pair is formed with these numbers. The rest can form two pairs. Hence total =

(options for pairing with 4).(One pair of the three remaining no.s).(rest 2 pairs)
$$=4.(^3C_2)(^4C_2)$$

In PHASE2, 4 has to pair with the pair carried over by $^3C_2$, since this is bigger than 4. The other two pair up. So this PHASE2 can be done in 1 way.

Hence a total of $=4.(^3C_2)(^4C_2)$ successful cases.

Total number of cases = (PHASE1)(PHASE2) $$\frac{8!}{2!2!2!2!}.\frac{4!}{2!2!}$$

Now find the probability.

Comment: Now if the question was for some larger number of tickets than 8, wouldn't this method be extremely brute force?

Comment: Yes, but I can't think of a more elegant method. However, you can develop efficient codes to handle bigger numbers.